# Dojo dijit.form.Select Validation Error Display

Tags: forms, validation, select, error-handling, dojo

I am finding that in **Dojo 1.7.3**, setting `required: true` on a *dijit.form.Select* does not properly apply a red bordered error display to the Select as it does with other dijits such as FilteringSelect. If it is in an error state and has focus, it displays the tooltip, but it doesn't apply the red borders to the Select input.

Past answers I've seen regarding this are:

1. Select wasn't originally constructed to allow for validation, so it is missing the proper classes/divs in its template (such as for the red box with exclamation point), meaning you'd need to add your own CSS.
2. A blank value for a Select box isn't necessarily invalid.

I found [this](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html) example page where a normal dijit.form.Select with `required: true` seems to work (almost) as expected. I say almost because it looks like it keeps its blue border with the red exclamation point box when it first loses focus and doesn't get the full red border until a secondary focus change (in Firefox, at least).

I haven't been able to discern anything in this example page that could be used to get the error formatting to work for *dijit.form.Select*. It does appear to be using Dojo 1.7.4, but I don't see anything in 1.7.4 release notes about the Select error display being fixed.

Has this not been considered a bug that needs to be fixed? Is there a way to easily apply the validation styles without having to mess with the dijit template?

Any help/ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a ticket about this in dojo's bug tracking system: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16792

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a relative link to a test file:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html